# Frames not working in Watin

Tags: c#, .net, watin, frames

I have read the posts noting that the use of frames broke in 2.1.  I've read how you find "iframe" in the watin code and change it to "frame".  I've recompiled and when I use my new dll in my project it gives me an error saying I've got the wrong .net version.  I need to work with frames in .net 3.5.  I freely admit that I'm not experienced enough to figure this out.  Is there someone who can compile a 3.5 version of the watin core with this change in it or can I pay someone who is experienced to get on my machine and help me properly compile the change to "frame".

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project's properties, Application settings -> Target framework and change it to .NET framework 3.5

Comment: I've done this now.  However, vs tells me it must reopen the app.  when it does, it's back at .net 4.0 again.  Any ideas?